# call parent ViewController instance method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i m adding a custom view to a view controller , by the following code

```
[bTVC addSubview:customView];
```

now i want to call a instance method of parent viewController in the custom view's class like this

```
[self.parentViewController instanceMethod];
```

is that possible ?  how can i do that ?

Comment: create an object of the parent view and use it to call its methods

Comment: but that would mean creating a new object .. 
cant i use the existing object of ViewController on which the custom view has been added ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the "normal" method should be to implement a property (not retained) delegate pointing to your parent viewController, but you may prefer to use something like this:

```
-(MyCustomUIViewController*)findParentUIViewControllerInSuperViews:(UIView*)myView {
    for (UIView* next = [myView superview]; next; next = next.superview) {
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[MyCustomUIViewController class]]) {
            return (MyCustomUIViewController*)nextResponder;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

now just call:

```
MyCustomUIViewController* myParentViewController = (MyCustomUIViewController*)[self findParentUIViewControllerInSuperViews:self];
[myParentViewController instanceMethod];
```

anyway, i also recommend you to learn how delegate works, it's useful in many cases and you'll surely need it sooner or later...

Answer (score 0):

There is no addSubview method in NSViewController. You can find it in NSView. 
if bTVC is an instance of NSView (or a subclass of) you can get what you call parent view by sending superview to self : [self superview] or self.superview. It'll return bTVC in your example.
NSViewController works differently you can read full documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: sorry , i am using UIViewController and UIView