# Call instance method in ViewController from View

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to call an instance method which is in my UIViewController from within a UIView. In my UIViewController I have something like:

```
-(void) test {
    NSLog(@"test");
}
```

In my UIViewController, I create an instance of my UIView like so:

```
draggableView = [[DraggableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 190, 280, 280)];
```

In my `draggableView`, I then want to call the `test` instance method. How do I do this without creating a new instance of the UIViewController?

I have [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579228/call-parent-viewcontroller-instance-method), but it doesn't seem like a very elegant solution and I get an error `"No visible @interface ..."`

Comment: Use a delegate (i.e. tell the view the viewcontroller-delegate to use and make the view call back on that delegate).

Comment: Thanks @trojanfoe, do you have a good example anywhere for me?

Comment: Delegates are very common in Objective-C and there are tons of examples on the net and questions on here.  For example: http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View does not have default method to access its view-controller object.
You need to pass the view-controller object into the view object yourself.
Typical way to do this is making a property.

```
@class ViewController;

@interface DraggableView : NSObject
@property (readwrite,nonatomic,assign) ViewController* theOwnerViewController;
@end

@implementation DraggableView
- (void)testCallingOwnerViewControllerMethod
{
    [self.theOwnerViewController test];
}
@end
```

You need to set the `theOwnerViewController` after you created the `DraggableView` object.

```
- (void)loadView
{
    draggableView = [[DraggableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 190, 280, 280)];
    draggableView.theOwnerViewController = self;
    //...extra view setup.
}
```

Use `assign` to avoid retain-cycle on the property.

#### Delegate pattern

You can do this by above pattern, but as you noticed, you need to *know* and forward-declare the owner view-controller class' name from its view (which is sub-node of the VC). Usually This is bad design choice because it's easily makes [*circular dependency*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425465/does-objective-c-allow-circular-dependencies) (or backward dependency), which usually creates tight-coupling.

Instead, you can use delegate pattern to avoid circular dependency issue.

```
@protocol TestDelegate
- (void)test;
@end

@interface DraggableView : NSObject
@property(readwrite,nonatomic,assign) id<TestDelegate> testDelegate;
@end

@implementation DraggableView
- (void)test
{
    [self.testDelegate test];
}
@end
```

You need to set the `testDelegate` after you created the `DraggableView` object.

```
@interface ViewController<TestDelegate>
@end
@implementation
- (void)test
{
    // do something.
}
- (void)loadView
{
    draggableView = [[DraggableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 190, 280, 280)];
    draggableView.testDelegate = self;
    //...extra view setup.
}
@end
```

In this case, you don't have to know the class name of the view object before you create. Any class which conforms `TestDelegate` protocol can be used, and now the view and VC are loosely-coupled via the protocol.

Comment: I did try this earlier, but I keep getting the error `No visible @interface declares the selector test`

Comment: @eskimo You can avoid the error by declaring the `@class` name before using it. Anyway delegate provides more flexibility with less dependency.

Comment: Thanks @Eonil. What do you mean by that (declaring the class name)?

Comment: The circular dependency problem is trivial to solve. The disadvantages of having the view know about the view controller are: increased coupling between the two classes; it becomes impossible to reuse the view in another context; and it also makes it possible for the view to control its controller, which will make the control flow hard to follow.

Comment: @DouglasHill I agree. Coupling is the problem rather then dependency.

Comment: @eskimo That specifically means `@class ViewController;` line. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789252/forward-declaration-for-objective-c-interfaces for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Eonil, got it working using the delegate. Much appreciated!